# ODBC connection to informix database on ubuntu

Tags: python, informix, pyodbc, unixodbc

I'm trying to connect to my informix database installed on Ubuntu 16.04 with Pyodbc and Unix ODBC but I'm getting this error:

> Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [unixODBC][Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]Unspecified System Error =  -23101. (-23101) (SQLDriverConnect)')

I'm using this python code:

```
import pyodbc
DRIVER = 'IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER'
SERVER = 'ol_informix1210' 
DATABASE = 'rays'
USER='informix'
PASS='Admin123'
constr = 'DRIVER={%s};SERVER=%s;DATABASE=%s;UID=%s;PWD=%s' % (DRIVER, SERVER, DATABASE, USER, PASS)
con = pyodbc.connect(constr)
```

to configure UnixODBC I used those two configuration file: 
odbc.ini:

```
[ODBC Data Sources]
Infdrv1=IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER
Infdrv2=IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER
;
; Define ODBC Database Driver's Below - Driver Configuration Section
;
[Infdrv1]
Driver=/opt/informix/lib/cli/iclit09b.so
Description=IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER
Database=rays
LogonID=informix
pwd=Admin123
Servername=ol_informix1210
TRANSLATIONDLL=/opt/informix/lib/esql/igo4a304.so
[Infdrv2]
Driver=/opt/informix/lib/cli/iclis09b.so
Description=IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER
Database=rays
LogonID=informix
pwd=Admin123
Servername=ol_informix1210
CursorBehavior=0
CLIENT_LOCALE=en_us.8859-1
DB_LOCALE=en_us.8859-1
TRANSLATIONDLL=/opt/informix/lib/esql/igo4a304.so;
; UNICODE connection Section
;
[ODBC]
;uncomment the below line for UNICODE connection
;UNICODE=UCS-4
;
; Trace file Section
;
UNICODE=UCS-2
Trace=0
TraceFile=/tmp/odbctrace.out
InstallDir=/opt/informix
TRACEDLL=idmrs09a.so
```

and odbcinst.ini:

```
[ODBC Drivers]
IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER=Installed
[IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER]
Driver=/opt/informix/lib/cli/iclit09b.so
Setup=/opt/informix/lib/cli/iclit09b.so
APILevel=1
ConnectFunctions=YYY
DriverODBCVer=03.51
FileUsage=0
SQLLevel=1
smProcessPerConnect=Y
```

Does any one know what's the issue here ?

Comment: Umm.. have you set the INFORMIXDIR environment variable?   In your case it should be set to INFORMIXDIR=/opt/informix. You also  will need LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$INFORMIXDIR/lib:$INFORMIXDIR/esql:$INFORMIXDIR/cli

Comment: Thank you for your answer: Yes I've already done that

Comment: And that still fails? "Unspecified System" basically means the driver (which was loaded because you can see the "[Informix][Informix ODBC Driver]" header in the error can't find the error message for the -23101 error number. Basically it can't find the messages files in $INFORMIXDIR/msg

Comment: Yes, but $INFORMIXDIR is well set, because I can access to my data base throw the terminal ... but I only can't thrw the ODBC connection

Comment: Are you using the same session (terminal) to access the ODBC driver?  if not maybe the session/user you are launching the ODBC application doesnt have it set. You could run something like truss/strace to trace the os functions the ODBC app does. It should show you why the msg files can't be located.

Comment: One explanation of the error is _-23101: Unable to load locale categories. 
— An invalid locale name was supplied for the locale initialization. The environment variable specifying the locale category has a wrong
value. — Check the value of the corresponding environment variable,
CLIENT_LOCALE or DB_LOCALE._ . It can also mean that INFORMIXDIR is not set correctly — the `$INFORMIXDIR/gls` directory does not contain the right information.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar problems when I tried to connect to informix DB via PHP. When I checked the environment variables from shell, I was able to see them but they were not set when I checked via info.php

So basically I had to hard code the environment variables in /etc/apache2/envvars

After that I was able to see the env variables both via terminal and info.php and the connection worked.

I hope this could help you ensure you have set the env variables correctly.

Thanks